# React Redux - action failing, parsing error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to learn react redux and I'm trying to create a simple example using a shopping list with get, delete and add items.

I have an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2xfk3h?file=src%2Freducers%2FitemReducer.js) that shows it working with get and delete items.

My problem is in the reducer with the add item.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bprixt?file=src/reducers/itemReducer.js) is the same example but with the additem in reducer.

```
case ADD_ITEM:
  return{
    ...state,
    items: [...state.items, {id: uuid(),  action.payload}]
  }
```

It's complaining about action.payload

The error I get locally is

```
./src/reducers/itemReducer.js
  Line 26:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  24 |       return{
  25 |         ...state,
> 26 |         items: [...state.items, {id: uuid(),  action.payload}]
     |                                                     ^
  27 |       }  
  28 |     default:
  29 |       return state
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you please specify the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an object with this statement `{id: uuid(), action.payload}`. You provide a key for the first entry but not one for the second. Looking at your items object it is expecting the name key.

Try changing it to this:
`{id: uuid(), name: action.payload}`

Comment: This works, but now when the item is added the text does not show

Comment: My bad, the key you are expecting appears to be name. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your action:

```
export const addItem = (name) =>{
  return{
    type: ADD_ITEM,
    payload: { name }
  }
}
```

then, edit your reducer:

```
export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return{
        ...state
      }
    case DELETE_ITEM:
      return{
        ...state,
        items: state.items.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload)
      }  
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return{
        ...state,
        items: [...state.items, {...action.payload, id: uuid()}]
      }  
    default:
      return state  
  }
}
```